# How do I tab between text boxes on a form in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm trying to get the functionality to tab to the next text box once the user has input their data for the previous text box. For example, once they filled in a company name I'd like to be able to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and set the focus on the next text box "Job Name". Is this done in the code or the form properties?

Here is some of my code. I'm unsure how to nest a `KeyEventsArgs` within these, which is how I've seen others set the focus to the next text boxes using the `KeyPress` function.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CompanyName = textBox1.Text;
    textBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    JobName = textBox2.Text;
    textBox2.AcceptsTab = true;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the question you've asked and the code sample provided, there seems to be somewhat of a disconnect between your approach and the desired functionality.

As you would like the user to be able to use the **Tab key** in order to shift keyboard focus between elements in the window, you need only provide a **TabIndex** attribute on each of your TextBox controls. There is no need to use the TextChanged events to achieve this and it can be done completely in XAML for simplicity's sake.

From how I interpret your question, your next follow-on will likely be:

> How do I initially give focus to a control when the application
>   starts?

To address this, there are a couple of alternatives available, simplest of which comes in the form of the FocusManager, which again I've illustrated usage of in XAML.

For convenience, here is a XAML-only implementation with TabIndex and FocusManager implemented:

```
<Window x:Class="tab_navigation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tab_navigation"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TbxCompanyName}">
<Grid Margin="10">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Label Content="Company Name:" Target="{Binding ElementName=TbxCompanyName}" />
            <TextBox Name="TbxCompanyName" TabIndex="0" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Content="Job Description:" Target="{Binding ElementName=TbxJobDescription}"/>
            <TextBox Name="TbxJobDescription" TabIndex="1" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Give me a shout if you need any further help, although I would strongly recommend checking out some of the MSDN resources first, particularly those concerning [Focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **UPDATE**: In response to comment regarding implementing the solution,
>   WPF has a different design and best practices from that of WinForms.
>   I would **strongly** make the case that you cease using Forms and instead use a Window or UserControl derived class in place of a Form in your WPF project unless there is a very, very good reason for doing so. If you continue to use a Form inside of your WPF project, you will indeed need to implement your own keyboard navigation logic inside that form, and bridge various other gaps you'll inevitably run into when trying to get a Form behave in a commonly acceptable way.
>   I'll instead show you how you can achieve your request using an objectively better and more suitable approach in WPF-only, using Window or UserControl elements. There is also a complete solution [zip downloadable here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vis02161dyetdwk/TabbedNavigation-Window.zip?dl=0).

WPF is by design a lot more modular than WinForms and splits the areas of concerns nicely by default, although most developers implement a design pattern ontop of this; MVVM is the current darling of WPF, and does add quite a lot of value to a project, although it is outside the scope of your question, so I shall instead address the question itself on the grounds of how to achieve the request in its most basic forms. Do please be aware though that this is not the entirely ideal solution and I would strongly recommend you learn and implement the MVVM pattern for WPF if you are not already familiar with it.

With that disclaimer out of the way, **instead of using a Form in WPF**, its more useful for us to make a class which derives from **Window**. An even more common scenario in WPF would be that you would want to have a single window whose content changes between different views, rather than say creating multiple windows, although again that is outside the scope of the question and would rely upon reading into Binding and MVVM. I'm going to be showing you a quick and easy way to get the functionality you've asked for, I'm just trying to iterate here that **this is not the norm** almost all of the time.

To make a working solution, do the following to your project:

1. Right click your project in the solution explorer (presuming you are using Visual Studio)
2. 'Add' a 'New Item...'.
3. Choose the 'Window (WPF)' template and name it. **I'm going to call it CustomerInformationEntry from here out**.
4. Open the **CustomerInformationEntry.xaml** file that has been created for us, **remove** the `<Grid></Grid>` tags and copy/paste this excerpt from the XAML I've already provided from above in their place:

`<Grid Margin="10">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Label Content="Company Name:" Target="{Binding ElementName=TbxCompanyName}" />
            <TextBox Name="TbxCompanyName" TabIndex="0" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Content="Job Description:" Target="{Binding ElementName=TbxJobDescription}"/>
            <TextBox Name="TbxJobDescription" TabIndex="1" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>`

5. Add `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TbxCompanyName}` to the **Window** element in **CustomerInformationEntry.xaml**.
6. This is our view or visual representation finished with now, and all that remains is to instanciate a new CustomerInformationEntry from our other Window or UserControl, and to then display it. In this case I'm going to be putting a button onto the **MainWindow.xaml**, and providing it a click event which will create the instance of our new Window:

   - In **MainWindow.xaml**  add `<Button Name="BtnOpenCustomerInformationEntry" Content="Enter Customer Information" Click="OpenCustomerInformationEntry"/>`. In my case I'll be adding the button inside my  object, although you can put it wherever you like if you've already created your initial window.
   - In **MainWindow.xaml.cs** we'll add a new private method which will be used by the Click event of your new button. Adding the following code:

`private void OpenCustomerInformationEntry(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomerInformationEntry myWindow = new CustomerInformationEntry();
            myWindow.Show();
        }`

That's it, you now have a button in your MainWindow.xaml which when clicked uses the OpenCustomerInformationEntry method defined in MainWindow.xaml.cs, which in turn makes an instance of your CustomerInformationEntry window and displays it.

If you would still rather stick with the Forms approach, you can do that by using [WindowsFormsHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx), usage of which is [discussed here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/).

Best Regards,
JC

Comment: I am using a windows form that opens when you press a button on the WPF form. So, there is not an option to use XAML... Also, I can get the focus to change using the tab by adding the following to the XAML on my WPF form: KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"   but I am still unable to tab through objects on my windows form

Comment: To confirm, are you using WPF or WinForms; the question was tagged WFP and you've referred to both forms and WPF. If it's the case you are using WPF but programatically creating the window, then you can simply make a new window or user control in your solution, add the xaml to it, and create an instance of that as your 'form' from the button press. Updated answer also with an example of this.

Comment: In relation to the keyboard navigation, setting the mode to cyclical re-enforces the default navigation strategy, although in and of itself does not designate controls as TabIndexes which can be used by the navigation. To achieve this you will still need to provide TabIndex in your controls, or make your own custom solution in addition to the one provided in WPF by default. This will work right out of the box if you make the WPF window or user control in XAML and instanciate it from your button, rather than making a new base window class as I understand from the comment.

Comment: After re-reading your comment, it seems that you're attempting to use a Form inside of a WPF project. Let me be the first to say that this is quite simply not a standard thing to do for various reasons. I've updated my answer now to reflect this, and provide a download to a working solution for you. If you would prefer to go with the Forms approach still, you will need to use [WindowsFormsHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) as discussed [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/)